# R xts and data.table and IDate

Tags: r, data.table, xts

This is an extension of this question [R xts and data.table](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9295209/4606130).

I see `as.xts.data.table` is a new addition to the `data.table` package.

When I set dates with `IDate` (integer dates), I then get errors when looking at the table after an `xts` conversion with this error message:

> Error in index.xts(x[1, ]) :    unsupported ‘indexClass’ indexing
>   type: IDate

**CODE SNIPPET**

```
library(data.table)
library(xts)

# I am setting dates as IDate here in example, but in my code 
#   I get a subset from elsewhere
dt <- data.table(date = c(as.IDate("2014-12-31"),
                          as.IDate("2015-12-31"),
                          as.IDate("2016-12-31")), 
                 nav = c(100,101,99),
                 key = "date")

str(dt)
# Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame':    3 obs. of  2 variables:
#   $ date: IDate, format: "2014-12-31" "2015-12-31" ...
# $ nav : num  100 101 99
# - attr(*, "sorted")= chr "date"
# - attr(*, ".internal.selfref")=<externalptr> 


#convert to xts for PerformanceAnalytics (IDate not supported)
dt.xts <- as.xts.data.table(dt) # seems to work okay but...

str(dt.xts) # gives indexing type error above
```

I understand `IDate` is still developing out - *"Still experimental!"*. What is the best way to get rid of the IDate type to use xts in the interim? [I tried forcing the type to no avail - `as.xts(as.Date(dt$date))` ]

Can a future `as.xts.data.table` fix the IDates?

*R3.2.2. versions: xts: 0.9-7 zoo: 1/7-12 data.table: 1.9.6*

Comment: Please file an issue: https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues

Comment: Ok @Roland done this as [#1499](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/1499)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update on 2016-04-13:**
This has just been fixed in recent development version of data.table. You don't need to handle conversion of `IDate` any more. Code from the question will work just fine.
Below outdated answer, useful for those on data.table 1.9.6 or lower.

---

You need to change your IDate field to Date before converting to xts. IDate and ITime types were not considered when `as.xts` method was developed.
Patch to support that can be made, there is already one bugfix related to `xts` waiting to be merged.
Solution to your problem:

```
library(data.table)
library(xts)
dt <- data.table(date = c(as.IDate("2014-12-31"),
                          as.IDate("2015-12-31"),
                          as.IDate("2016-12-31")), 
                 nav = c(100,101,99),
                 key = "date")
dt[, date := as.Date(as.integer(date))]
dt.xts <- as.xts.data.table(dt)
```

Comment: Thanks @jangorecki. I did a workaropund like this. The one problem with dt[, date := as.Date(as.integer(date))] - it strips out the key as "date" is seen to have changed. (Others be aware of this and then rekey your table with `setkey()`)